# Bounty strings are not used in localization engine

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, localization, russian-stackoverflow

Looks like some strings pertain to bounty are not used in localization engine (despite of existed translations). In particular:

- [with no winning answer](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265085?key=0958c609743a6a73840f0b99aa0ad4c0)
- [worth $amount$ reputation](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/42116413?key=ea9323be3807b074bc7b5a5ef4ad5ee7)
- [with $answerlink$ chosen](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265096?key=8e19836534bee31afed57ff8df0e294f)

Seen [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/667511/revisions):

> [image: unlocalized bounty]

And [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/496002/revisions):

> [image: answer chosen]

Linked bug report on ruSO meta: [Отсутствует перевод сообщений о конкурсных вопросах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3203/176217)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that translations are used now. You can check the links to the revision pages from the question's body.

But these still need polished translations from translators. A better solution would be to use full sentences instead of concatenating the string from several phrases. E.g.:

> Bounty ended with no winning answer by {username}

now is still constructed from:

1. > Bounty ended
2. > with no winning answer
3. > by {username}

Such strings are too hard to localize in particular due to the fixed order of phrases.

Related question: [Impossible to localize flag summary page title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305001/339911)