# Impossible to localize flag summary page title

Tags: bug, status-deferred, localization, flag-history

As far as I see filtering flags on the flag summary page uses simple words combining to create a full sentence as a title. E.g. title for helpful flags on comments:

> [image]

Such approach is completely unacceptable for localized sites. Full sentences should be used instead for each filtering type.

Answer (score 3):

I agree.

But...

- there's ~30 possible combinations
- this is one of the rare cases where we have enum-combination-explosion

The options for fixing this are to either generate all the combinations once (template + condition) ( == maintenance hell), or extend our localization back end / templating / compiler to support generating those ( == considerable effort).

I'll see what I can do.

Comment: 30 different strings are OK. [81 same - not OK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301810/339911).

Comment: Any updates on it?

Comment: @Suvitruf What do we say to the god of death?

Comment: @Suvitruf knowing the question’s source is enough to get an answer on your question.

Comment: How about something like `$flags_title_status$ $flags_title_group$ flags` instead of `$status$ $group$ flags`?